# Complex Analysis: Confirmation for a question in my textbook?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm being told that $$\frac{\exp{(1+i3\pi})}{\exp{(-1+i\pi /2})}= \exp(2)i$$
I keep getting $-\exp(2)i$. I have no idea how they didn't get that to be negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac{-exp(1)}{exp(-1)i} = exp(2)i$

Answer (score 3):

Since $$e^{1 + 3\pi i} = e\cdot e^{3\pi i} = e\cdot (-1) = -e$$ and $$e^{-1 + \pi i/2} = e^{-1} e^{\pi i/2} = e^{-1}\cdot i$$ we have

$$\frac{e^{1 + 3\pi i}}{e^{-1 + \pi i/2}} = \frac{-e}{e^{-1}\cdot i} = ie^2.$$

Comment: Silly me, blew through it too fast to not just multiply the $i$. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Relatively straightforward :

$$\frac{\exp{(1+i3\pi})}{\exp{(-1+i\pi /2})}= \frac{e \exp({i3\pi})}{e^{-1}\exp{(i\frac{\pi}{2}})} =  \frac{e\times(-1) }{e^{-1}\times i} = -e^2 \frac{1}{i}$$

But $\frac{1}{i} = -i$ (because $-1 = i\times i$ then you divide by $i$) so you get

$$\frac{\exp{(1+i3\pi})}{\exp{(-1+i\pi /2})}=ie^2$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{e^{1+3i\pi}}{e^{-1+i\pi/2}} = \frac{e \cdot e^{3i\pi}}{\frac{1}{e}e^{i\pi/2}}$$ Now by Euler's identity we have $e^{i\pi/2} = i$ and $e^{3i\pi} = -1$. Hence $$\frac{e \cdot e^{3i\pi}}{\frac{1}{e}e^{i\pi/2}} = \frac{-e}{\frac{i}{e}}$$ Now multiply the expression by $\frac{ei}{ei}$ to clean it up, and we'll see $$\frac{-e}{\frac{i}{e}} \cdot \frac{ei}{ei} = \frac{-e^2i}{-1} = ie^2$$